# DynamoDB has very little support docs on the web

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, documentation

I am trying to use DynamoDB for the backend DB of my application, but am having a hard time finding useful information associated to it.

What is the best source of examples and tutorial information for syntax structures etc?

AWS docs are really confusing. Or am I the only person sitting with these problems?

Oh and is the newly launched AWS DocumentDB (Basically MongaDB) going to make DynamoDB pointless to learn, or is there still merit in learning DynamoDB?

Answer (score 1):

The pricing model between DocumentDB and DynamoDB are completely different -  there is definitely a place for both - imo, dynamodb is not going away any time soon.

As far as tutorials - there are tons of AWS reinvent videos on youtube, and this site allows you to search/find them easily: https://reinventvideos.com/. Good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, that's a super useful site! I have started working through the invent clips a while ago, some really eye-opening stuff, just strange to me that it feels like there are extremely few blog-posts, sample code etc. Like took me almost a whole day to find the syntax for using `begins_with` ...